# Data not encoding correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, odbc, filemaker

Let me detail my current setup first:

Windows 10 running IIS 10, PHP 5.6,
FileMaker Server 14 with ODBC enabled

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0.4 and it is configured to use utf8 encoding also my odbc dsn is set to use utf8, I don't have any problem displaying characters like "Á" or "ñ", the problem comes when inserting my data.

```
// DATA ARRAY
$data = array(
            "id" => null,
            "idPregunta" => (int)$idPreg,
            "idEntrevistado" => $entrevistado,
            "Valor" => "íóú",
            "FechaCreacion" => $fecha
            );


// MODEL SCRIPT
$this->db->insert("Respuesta", $data);
```

Displaying `$sql = $this->db->set($data)->get_compiled_insert('Respuesta');` correctly shows that the data I'm inserting is what I have written but in my database is inserted like `Ã­Ã³Ãº`. Is not a problem within the database, using FileMaker Pro to directly insert this characters doesn't show the same encoding issue.

**config/database.php**

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'encuestas',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'IIS',
'password' => '123456',
'database' => 'PollServiceSurveys',
'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**EDIT:**

It appears is a problem with the ODBC driver, a quick workaround is to use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` stripping html tags before.

Comment: Javier, one thing is what you **see** on your screen and a _totally_ different thing is what you **stored** in your database. The very same database byte vales can be displayed in a totally different way on two clients configured in a different way. As you want to check the encoding used in the database I'd suggest you to directly check hex bytes stored in the db. The less software layers you will use to check database content the better.

Comment: how does your database config array look like?